# Fragment manager's `getBackStackEntryCount` method returns zero

Tags: android

Why does my fragment manager's `getBackStackEntryCount` method return zero?

I've spent an hour or checking SO for an answer to this question. I've

1. used the fragment support manager with `getSupportFragmentManager`
2. called `executePendingTransactions`
3. imported `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

but `getBackStackEntryCount` keeps returning zero.

Any idea why? Doesn't my code look correct?

Here's my code

```
private void injectFragment(){

    // Get the fragment 
    StepsFragment stepsFragment = new StepsFragment();

    // Get the support fragment manager
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Inject the fragment into a frame layout
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_layout, stepsFragment)
            .commit();

    // I read that I should execute pending transactions before calling
    // getBackStackEntryCount
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

    // This log prints `getBackStackEntryCount returns 0`
    int entryCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    Log.v(TAG,"getBackStackEntryCount returns "+String.valueOf(entryCount));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getBackStackEntryCount()` is 0 because you have not added any Fragment transactions to the `FragmentManager`'s back stack.

Note that each `FragmentManager` has its own backstack (so a Fragment's child `FragmentManager` stack would be different from the containing `Activity`'s fragment backstack), and it is also distinct from the application's Activity back stack.

If you were to add your transaction to the back stack like so, it would return 1:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_layout, stepsFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```